# Angular 2 Material: "Expression was changed [..]" with mdInput

Tags: angular, angular-material2, zone.js

```
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput type="number" min="0" [(ngModel)]="troup.amount" *ngIf="wave.Mode === SimulationModes.Normal">
</md-input-container>
```

I've recently updated from the previous version of material angular to the newest one, and needed to change all my inputs to match the new criteria with `<md-input-container>` instead of `<md-input>`.

When compiling, I get a Zone Error telling that the value changed from "undefined" to ''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work, you no longer should put any `*ngIf` in the `mdInput` directive, but this should be placed on the container instead:

```
<md-input-container *ngIf="wave.Mode === SimulationModes.Normal">
   <input mdInput type="number" min="0" [(ngModel)]="troup.amount">
</md-input-container>
```

This solves the issue.